# Output to text file from a powershell/WMI script

Tags: powershell, file-io, batch-file

I am a complete noob when it comes to programming, so please bear with me. I did do a thorough search of the site and didn't find anything which helped me figure out the issues.

I am running the following WMI script against a list of PC's on the domain to remotely and silently uninstall Java Auto Updater from a list of computers.

```
wmic /failfast:on /node:@"c:\names.txt" product where "name like 'Java Auto 
Updater'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

What i am looking to do is this. I would like to have the output from this script go to a text file, and show if the uninstall was successful or not. When i run the script, I get a message saying "workstation name" - No instances available, if the PC is offline at the time. I would like for this to show in the text file output when I run the script, since my boss wants me to document the fact that I successfully uninstalled the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
wmic /failfast:on /node:@"c:\names.txt" product where "name like 'Java Auto 
Updater'" call uninstall /nointeractive | Out-File -FilePath C:\results.txt
```